# Integrate a two form on torus

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, manifolds, stokes-theorem

I have a curve that looks like the one shown in the figure below.
[image: Curve]
The curve is defined on a torus. I would like to compute the integral of a two form over the area enclosed by this curve. I understand using Stokes' theorem I can get the line integral of the corresponding one form along the boundary, however, I would like to stick to integrating the two form.

What is the area enclosed that I should consider?

Answer (score 3):

Some closed curves are the boundaries of areas and others are not. The number of different curves that are *not* boundaries is measured by the *first homology group of the space*. The torus has first homology group $\mathbb{Z}^2$, which means there are two independent curves that aren't the boundaries of areas. These two curves are precisely the (non-contractible) longitude and meridian loops. So the curve you've drawn is not the boundary of any area!

Comment: My thoughts exactly!

Comment: PS: you can only convert the integral of an $n$-form into a boundary integral of an $(n-1)$-form if the $n$-form is *exact*. So even if your curve *was* the boundary of an area, one would need for your 2-form to be an exact form within that area.

Comment: Your "So the curve you've drawn ..." statement needs some explanation!

Comment: Thank you for the answers.
From my understanding, Stokes' theorem does not require a form to be exact. It just requires the manifold to be orientable and related the integral of a differential form over a boundary to the integral of the form's exterior derivative over the area enclosed by the boundary.  The exactness of the form is not a prerequisite. 

Robert Lewis, please explain a little more.  How does Stokes' theorem fail then because nowhere in Stokes' theorem is anything about odd curves like this one mentioned.

Comment: @JaskaranGrover Yes, note that one side of Stokes' theorem involves *the form's exterior derivative*. So the 2-form you're integrating over the area is necessarily exact. As for your second comment, note that Stokes' theorem takes as given the existence of an area $M$ and a boundary $\partial M$. There is no such $M$ corresponding to your boundary and so Stokes' theorem simply doesn't apply.

Comment: @gj255, thanks a lot for the help, that clarifies things a lot.